# Iterate over list of iterators linq

Tags: c#, linq, iterator

List enumerators not working in case when they are put in a list. For example in case of two lists (two enumerators)

```
public void test()
{
    var firstList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    var secondList = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
    var lists = new List<List<int>>();
    lists.Add(firstList);
    lists.Add(secondList);

    // Not working
    var iterators = lists.Select(x => x.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
    iterators.ForEach(x => x.MoveNext());
    iterators.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Current));

    // Working
    var firstIterator = iterators[0]; 
    var secondIterator = iterators[1];
    firstIterator.MoveNext(); secondIterator.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(firstIterator.Current);
    Console.WriteLine(secondIterator.Current);
}
```

the first part is not working and it prints `0 0`, while the second part is working and it prints `1 4`.

I don't understand what is mistake with the first part and how it can be solved.

Comment: do you specifically need to use iterators?

Comment: `x` and `iterators[0]` are not the same references. `x` is a local copy in each `ForEach` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the [`List<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a [`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s(v=vs.110).aspx) *mutable struct*.

When you assign it to a variable and call `MoveNext` and `Current`, it works. But when passed to delegate, it is passed by value, hence the delegate receives a copy so calling `MoveNext` has no effect of the original `struct` `Current`.

Just one of the side effects of the mutable structs.

If you change

```
x => x.GetEnumerator()
```

to

```
x => (IEnumerator<int>)x.GetEnumerator()
```

or

```
x => x.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()
```

both snippets will work because now the `iterators` will contain a boxed references of the returned structs.

Comment: Both options are wokring. Tnx for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you run 2 separate `.ForEach()` in the not working part. Do both actions in 1 foreach (`MoveNext()`, then print). `MoveNext` will not be remembered in a `.Foreach()` for a good explaination: [Go to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44198312/2885376)

**This:**

```
iterators.ForEach(x => x.MoveNext());
iterators.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Current));
```

**Becomes:**

```
iterators.ForEach(x => { x.MoveNext(); Console.WriteLine(x.Current); });
```

Comment: It does not explain why iterators remain in default state after first ForEach

Comment: I need moving and using iterators to be in different line. Also, if I do `iterators[0].MoveNext();` and then in next line `iterators[0].Current` it will also not work.

Comment: @Petar Maybe specify that? Looking for you now for a better solution

Comment: @Petar Ivan has a solution

Answer (score 1):

List's enumerator is implemented as a value type ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)):

```
iterators[0].GetType().IsValueType // true
```

That means - iterators are passed by value when you are passing them to the methods (i.e. copy of iterator is passed instead of passing a reference to iterator instance). `ForEach` method simply executes an action in a loop:

```
iterators.ForEach(copy => copy.MoveNext());
```

Action delegate is a method, so you are passing a *copy* of each iterator to this method. So original iterators remain unchanged. And when you call `ForEach` second time, again, copies of original untouched iterators are passed there:

```
iterators.ForEach(newCopy => Console.WriteLine(newCopy.Current));
```

But original iterators are in the initial state (before the first item) that is why you see default values of integer type when you read `Current` value.

You can either work with single copy of iterator:

```
iterators.ForEach(copy => { copy.MoveNext(); Console.WriteLine(copy.Current); });
```

Or box value type to pass it by reference (note that type of `iterators` list will change):

```
var iterators = lists.Select(x => (IEnumerable<int>)x.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
```